# .vimrc:2: command not found: colorscheme

Tags: vim, color-scheme

I'm trying to change the color scheme on my vim editor.

I put this on the .vimrc file

```
set t_Co=256
colorscheme molokai
```

I have the molokai.vim file on .vim/colors

And when I try to load the .vimrc file with the `source` command (on Mac OS X) I get this error

```
.vimrc:2: command not found: colorscheme
```

Could you help me?

Comment: I was trying to run source .vimrc and @paxdiablo told me that this will not work. So finally, I didn't and I add a line to my .vimrc and it works!
My file .vimrc finished is
`set t_Co=256`
`syntax enable`
`colorscheme molokai`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It appears that you're "loading" the `.vimrc` file by trying to run it within a shell. Because that's the sort of message you'll get if you try to *execute* it, with something like:

```
./.vimrc
```

or:

```
source .vimrc
```

(most shells having a `set` command so they're unlikely to complain about that first line).

That's not how the `.vimrc` file is processed, `vim` itself will process the file as it starts up.

All you need to do is edit the file (and save it of course) then, the next time you start a `vim` session, it will pick up the changes.

Comment: @navamario, you don't source it, `vim` itself loads it when you run the editor - see the update.

Comment: But when I open vim I can`t see the colors of molokai.vim

Comment: @navamario, that's a totally different issue, worthy of a different question. This particular error is because you're trying to source a file that's not a valid `bash` script. Run a vim session then enter `:color` and see what it prints at the bottom of the screen. If it's default (or something other than molokai), then it's not being picked up. If that's the case, ask a _new_ question.

Comment: Thank you for your help, you are right... when I run `:color` on vim I get `molokai`. So the issue is another different.

Answer (score 1):

The correct command for colorscheme is `color molokai`. Try that instead of `colorscheme molokai`.

Comment: The correct command _is_ `colorscheme`, which may be abbreviated to as little as `colo`.

Answer (score 1):

An issue I found is that on some Debian Distros, only vim-tiny is installed, which is a light weight version of vim and is missing a lot of functionality.

Try running

```
sudo apt-get install vim-gui-common
sudo apt-get install vim-runtime
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `:help colorscheme` in vim, or :colo[rscheme]